# "Solvitas perambulum": Is this real Latin?

Tags: translation-explanation

I've seen the phrase **Solvitas perambulum** translated [in many places](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solvitas+perambulum%22) as "Solve it while you walk." But I don't understand the grammar, and I find myself doubting that it's really Latin.

Here are my thoughts so far. *Solvitas* sounds like an abstract noun, meaning something like "being-solved-ness". But this noun doesn't seem to exist, and I think that a verb is needed, anyway. If *solvitas* is a verb, then it sounds like its infinitive would be *solvitare,* but there is no such verb. Maybe it would be a frequentative of [*solvere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solvo#Latin), but I haven't found that. *Perambulum* seems to mean not the act of walking (and then it would need to be in the ablative case), but a walkway or alley.

Is *Solvitas perambulum* fake Latin—or, if it's real, how does the grammar work? If there is a real Latin expression for this notion of relenting from effortful exertion on solving a problem and taking a leisurely walk to let your subconscious work on it, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be a distortion of the phrase [*solvitur ambulando*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvitur_ambulando) "it is solved by walking". As fdb says, neither word is correct Latin.

Comment: Good point.....

Answer (score 10):

This is fake Latin, but formed from two genuine words: solvo means “to release, set free, solve” and perambulo means “to walk through”; but neither “solvitas” nor “perambulum” means anything in Latin. It is internet nonsense.